# Why does the category of abelian groups satisfy the axiom AB6?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, abelian-groups

In his Tohoku article, Grothendieck says that the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups satisfies the axiom AB6, namely

"All small colimits exist in $\mathbf{Ab}$. Moreover for any index family $J$ and filtered categories $I_j, j\in J$, with functors $I_j\to \mathbf{Ab}, i\mapsto M_i$, the natural map

$ 
\underset{\substack{\rightarrow \\ (i_j\in I_j)_j}}{\lim} \prod_{j\in J} M_{i_j} \rightarrow \prod_{j\in J}\underset{\substack{\rightarrow \\ i_j\in I_j}}{\lim}M_{i_j} $

is an isomorphism."

It seems that this is saying that filtered limits and arbitrary products commute, but I don't think that this commutation happens.

Let us consider, for example (this is probably not the simplest example, but it is how I recognized the problem), a profinite space $S=\lim_i S_i$, projective limit of finite discrete sets $S_i$, where $i\in I=\{\text{finite quotients of } S\}$. For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let us consider the family $I_j=I$, with functors $I_j\to \mathbf{Ab}, i\mapsto \mathrm{Map}(S_i,\mathbb{Z})$ the abelian group of maps of sets from $S_i$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

The term on the left is, if I understood correctly, the abelian group

$\underset{\substack{\rightarrow\\(i\in I)_n}}{\lim} \prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathrm{Map}(S_i,\mathbb{Z})=\underset{\substack{\rightarrow\\(i\in I)_n}}{\lim} \mathrm{Map}(S_i,\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z})$

i.e. the abelian group of continuous function from $S$ to $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$, where the latter has the **discrete topology** (every map from the profinite $S$ to a discrete abelian group factors via some quotient $S_i$).

On the other hand, the term on the right is

$\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \underset{\substack{\rightarrow\\ i\in I}}{\lim} \mathrm{Map}(S_i,\mathbb{Z})=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{Cont}(S,\mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{Cont}(S,\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z})$

which is the abelian group of continuous functions $S\to \prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$, where this time the latter has the **product topology**.

Since the continuous identity morphism from the discrete $\prod \mathbb{Z}$ to itself with the product topology is not a homeomorphism, the two abelian groups $\mathrm{Cont}(S,(\prod\mathbb{Z})^{\delta})$ and $\mathrm{Cont}(S,(\prod\mathbb{Z})$ cannot coincide for all profinite space $S$.

I am sure that in the formulation of Grothendieck there are no errors, so I guess I misunderstood the meaning of the left-hand side (the filtered colimit of the products): can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure where continuity is coming in in your discussion -- $Ab$ is just the category of abelian groups, with no topologies in sight.

Comment: @TimCampion Certain limits of hom-sets of discrete objects can be expressed concisely as hom-sets of topological objects, and this can be used as a calculational tool even in discrete categories, though one expects it can almost always be removed if desired.

Comment: Continuity comes into the discussion just as an example: as I said, it is probably not the best example but it is how I recognized that filtered colimits and infinite products do not commute. In my example, the colimit of the infinite product of $\mathrm{Map}(S_i,\mathbb{Z})$ is the abelian group of continuous functions from $S$ to $\prod_n\mathbb{Z}$ (with discrete topology), while the infinite product of the colimits gives the abelian group of continuous. functions from $S$ to $\prod_n\mathbb{Z}$ (with product topology), which are apriori different.

Comment: Thanks. Reflecting on Will Sawin's answer, I think part of the confusion is that AB6 is not really about [commutativity of limits and colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutativity+of+limits+and+colimits), but rather it's an instance of the underveloped theory of [distributivity of limits over colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributivity+of+limits+over+colimits).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think the confusion was precisely about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects we are taking the limit over in the left side are $(i_j \in I_j)_j$, i.e. tuples of, for each $j\in J$, an element $i_j$ of $I_j$. These are the same as elements of $\prod_{j\in J}$.

Thus, the left side is a limit over $\prod_{j\in J} I_j$.

On the other hand, you have defined $I_j = I$ for all $j$ and then taken the limit over $I$.  Of course in this case $I$ embeds into $\prod_{j\in J} I$ as a "diagonal" subset, but not every element is bounded by an element on the diagonal, unless $I$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification: I got confused with the term on the left. Hence, in this particular example, the left-hand side is given by the colimit of $\mathrm{Cont}(S_i,\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z})$ with $i$ varying in the filtered system $I^{\mathbb{N}}$, right? (I guess it should be filtered with the lexicographic order).

Comment: @rtwo Your formula doesn't typecheck since $S_i$ for $i\in I^{\mathbb N}$ is not well-defined. It's just the limit of $\prod_{n\in \mathbb N} \operatorname{Map} (S_{i_n}, \mathbb Z)$ over tuples $(i_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.